# users with no questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I have the habit of everytime someone answers/comment one of my questions, i go trhu their list of questions and see if I can answer/contribute to any of the unanswered ones.

A few days ago I started to have some trouble on windows and the users answering windows questions have lots of answers and reputation, but zero questions.

I thought everyone had to ask questions to even start to be able to reply... Or do they delete their old questions for some reason?

Comment: Nope. [You don't have to ask any questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/488657/bart).

Comment: Wow - I'm impressed, @Bart.  You're a member of a tiny group of people who never need to ask for help on SO :)

Comment: Don't be impressed @AdamRackis. The questions I have are apparently so unoriginal that they are already answered.

Comment: I only have 1 answer in SO. Between SO and Google I have always found a suitable answer. If more users did this duplicate questions would be avoided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [answer a question with 1 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts), which you start with.

Comment: good point. maybe i was just confused... or did it change at some point? anyway, that answers it. waiting for the time to accept :)

Comment: @gcb I don't believe it's changed. At least, I earned my first rep on StackOverflow over two years ago [by answering a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702999/basic-mysql-problem/6703015#6703015).

Comment: i'm a month short of 4yrs :) but you are probably right. I'm just confusing things.